# Kotlin on Windows - error not caught using try/catch blocks

Tags: windows, kotlin, error-handling, try-catch

I'm new to Kotlin on Windows, and I have no idea why the screen shows java.io.FileNotFoundException but cannot catch any error at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
try {
        val writer = PrintWriter("something.txt")
}
catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        println("Catch");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your catch block catches a specific type of exception: `NumberFormatException`.

If you want to catch `FileNotFoundException`, you have to specify this one in the catch block, or add another catch block.